# which type of replication should i use?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication

I want to use replication for synchronising two server.
When i make changes in 1st server Data that should reflect on 2nd server.
so I am confused in choosing type of Replication.
so Please Help me.
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

It depends on

1.How quick you want to see data changes
2.Do you want to replicate only changes

If you want to see data changes with near real time latency and only want to replicate changes, you can use Transational replication

Comment: thanks #TheGameiswar..and Why should  not merge replication?

Comment: Try reading about that to see why it doesn't help in this case